# New to programming, Java.lang.NullPointerException with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, program-entry-point

I'm trying tackle this problem for a few days now but with no success. 
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Portefeuille {
private ArrayList<Woning> woningen;

public Portefeuille(){
    woningen = new ArrayList<Woning>();
}

public void voegToe(Woning w){
    if(woningen.contains(w)==false)
        woningen.add(w);
    else
        System.out.println(w.toString()+" komt al voor en is daarom niet toegevoegd.");
}

public ArrayList<Woning> woningenTot(int maxprijs){
    ArrayList<Woning> totaal = new ArrayList<Woning>();
    for(int i=0; i<woningen.size(); i++){
        if((woningen.get(i)).KostHooguit(maxprijs))
            totaal.add(woningen.get(i));
    }
    return totaal;
}

public static Portefeuille read(String infile){
    Portefeuille woningen = new Portefeuille();
    try
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(infile);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        int aantalwoningen = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<aantalwoningen; i++){
            Woning woning = Woning.read(sc);
            woningen.voegToe(woning);
        }
        System.out.println(woningen.toString());
        sc.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }
 return null;
 }
}
```

And here is the main file

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Portefeuille bestand = Portefeuille.read("in.txt");
    ArrayList<Woning> WTot = bestand.woningenTot(21500);

}
}
```

The error i am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test2.main(Test2.java:6)

I would really appreciate if someone could just at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Jaspreet

Comment: What the..? Can you please write above each code whats the file and also what is "KostHooguit" in (woningen.get(i)).KostHooguit(maxprijs)? And please full stack trace

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a NullPointerException when you end up trying to call a method on a reference that points to null, rather than an object. In your case, that would be `bestand.woningenTot(21500);` because the call to `Portefeuille.read("in.txt");` always returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Portefeuille.read("in.txt")` returns `null` instead of `woningen`.

```
    public static Portefeuille read(String infile){
        Portefeuille woningen = new Portefeuille();
        try
        {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(infile);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            int aantalwoningen = sc.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<aantalwoningen; i++){
                Woning woning = Woning.read(sc);
                woningen.voegToe(woning);
            }
            System.out.println(woningen.toString());
            sc.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
          }
     return woningen ;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you return `null` in your static read function... So you cant acces the object in line6.
Try to return `woningen` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The method Portefeuille.read always returns null. You need to return the Portefeuille you are creating.

Side comments:
- Call close always in a finally section
- Use enhanced looks instead of normal for loops. Like for(String s: collectionOfStrings)
- Try to program using interfaces instead of concrete classes if possible. E.g.: use List instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks to me like

```
public static Portefeuille read(String infile)
```

is always returning null. Perhaps there should be a

```
return woningen;
```

after sc.close();